# android manifest application 3 errors detected

Tags: android

I am trying to build a mobile app for android,using ADT,and i get a weird error for AndroidManifest.xml,it says that are actually 3 errors detected,in 'Application' tab.

Below is the content of the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.example.mfc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application>  <activity android:name="Home" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity></application>


</manifest>
```

Can anyone tell me which is the issue?

Comment: If you are getting an error at the android:name of the activity element that could mean the Activity doesn't exist or you haven't provided the correct path to it.

Comment: just for the future: ever, EVER post the errors you get. if you don't make this, it's hard to help you and you get (probably) down votes. so pls post the errors you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Its incorrect path as well as wrong location of **xmlns:android**
2. The path should be `.Home` and Home must `extends Activity` SuperClass
3. and There must be a launcher activity or service to start with

Should look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.photon.trackme"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.photon.trackme.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

### Note:

Where activity name = [Class name which extends `Activity` super class]
like: `com.photon.trackme.MainActivity` or simply `.MainActivity`

and

```
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

this defines that it is a launcher activity

Comment: If you're going to provide code in an answer then please format it correctly otherwise it is useless to the person who asked the question.

Comment: is it okey i may miss something if some one finds then he/she can edit i missed that thanks for pointing it

Comment: My point is simply that somebody else shouldn't have to spend time editing your answer. When asking a question or posting an answer on SO, there is a Preview pane - check over your Q or A before posting. Let's face it we're coders here - a single character in the wrong place or missing can be a major problem either at compile time or run time. Sorry for being pedantic but we have to be precise.

Comment: ya i agree but if some one miss then it could be done by others as i said; but if someone point rather than editing it as you did then he/she will edit as i did Thanks

Comment: Great,the launcher was the issue.I didn't post error because it didn't say any,just the number of errors in the 'Application' tab.